# Path property of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, path, filesystemwatcher

I'm making an application in which I open a txt file using an OpenFileDialog.

Everything works great and I read and process information.

Now i want to use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor any possible changes to the file.

When I try to assign the file path to the object I get an exception:

```
...

 public string PathOpenFile = null; 

...

 PathOpenFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;

 MyFileSystemWatcher.Path = PathOpenFile;
```

> The message that appears says:
>   "The directory name C:\Users\fromo\Desktop\DATA-TRAMA(192.168.1.5_PinPad_UNO)test2.txt isn't invalid"

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: "The directory name xxx **isn't in**valid" ?!

Comment: Use FolderBrowserDialog to select a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry for my mistake ( isn't invalid"), the correct is "isn't valid"

The solution to my problem is:

PathOpenFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;

MyFileSystemWatcher.Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(PathOpenFile);